# Mongodb:Aggregation query to return top 5 performers of month

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need top 5 customer of every month who have maxium sale.

here is some json example of my collection

```
[ {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c6cf92bd95bb300159ccde5"),
        "userId" :ObjectId("12332xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
        "sale":555,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-02-20T11:52:27.244+05:00")
       },
     {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c6cf92bd95bb300159ccde5"),
        "userId" :ObjectId("123ww2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
        "sale":600,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-03-20T11:52:27.244+05:00")
       }]
```

here is my query which i am trying

```
[
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { 
            $month: "$createdAt",
          },
          sales: {$sum:"$sale"}.
          customer:{$first:"$customer"},
          numberofSales: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      },
      { $sort: { _id: 1 } }
    ]
```

it return only one customer of the month , i need top 5 performer of every month

Answer (score 0):

I even did not believe that it is possible to get what you want with clear request, but here it is

```
db.getCollection('stack54783009').aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { 
            month:{$month: "$createdAt"},
            year:{$year: "$createdAt"},
            user:"$userId"
          },
          sales: {$sum:"$sale"},
          customer:{$first:"$customer"},
          numberofSales: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      },
      { $sort: { "_id.year": 1,"_id.month": 1,sales:-1 } },    
      { $group : { _id : {m:"$_id.month",y:"$_id.year"}, data: { $push: {sales:"$sales",numberofSales:"$numberofSales",userId:"$_id.user",customer:"$customer"} } } },
      { $unwind: { path: "$data", includeArrayIndex: "order" } },
      { $match: {order:{$lte:4}}},
      { $project:{
            _id: 0,
            m:"$_id.m",
            y:"$_id.y",
            user:"$data.userId",
            numberofSales:"$data.numberofSales",
            customer: "$data.customer",
            sales:"$data.sales"
      }},
      { $sort: {y:1,m:1,sales:-1}}
])
```

You should properly group documents

```
...
$group: {
  _id: { 
    month:{$month: "$createdAt"},
    year:{$year: "$createdAt"},
    user:"$userId"
  },
...
```

then sort, push data in array, unwind it with array indexes, limit 5 elements (or less) and get plain documents.

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "m" : 2,
    "y" : 2019,
    "user" : 2.0,
    "numberofSales" : 1.0,
    "sales" : 600.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "m" : 2,
    "y" : 2019,
    "user" : 1.0,
    "numberofSales" : 1.0,
    "sales" : 555.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "m" : 2,
    "y" : 2019,
    "user" : 7.0,
    "numberofSales" : 1.0,
    "sales" : 90.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "m" : 3,
    "y" : 2019,
    "user" : 2.0,
    "numberofSales" : 4.0,
    "sales" : 1900.0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "m" : 3,
    "y" : 2019,
    "user" : 3.0,
    "numberofSales" : 1.0,
    "sales" : 1600.0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "m" : 3,
    "y" : 2019,
    "user" : 5.0,
    "numberofSales" : 2.0,
    "sales" : 860.0
}

/* 7 */
{
    "m" : 3,
    "y" : 2019,
    "user" : 6.0,
    "numberofSales" : 2.0,
    "sales" : 600.0
}

/* 8 */
{
    "m" : 3,
    "y" : 2019,
    "user" : 4.0,
    "numberofSales" : 2.0,
    "sales" : 120.0
}
```

But you can simplify query executing:

```
db.getCollection('stack54783009').aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { 
            month:{$month: "$createdAt"},
            year:{$year: "$createdAt"},
            user:"$userId"
          },
          sales: {$sum:"$sale"},
          customer:{$first:"$customer"},
          numberofSales: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      },
      { $sort: { "_id.year": 1,"_id.month": 1,sales:-1 } },    
])
```

and handle result on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but i want result something like that 
`[
 {
  "m":1,
  "numberOfSale1":15214.21,
  "customer1": ObjecId("11111111111"),
  "numberOfSale2":13524.22,
 "customer2": ObjecId("11111111111"),  
},
 {
  "m":2,
  "numberOfSale1":13973,
  "customer1": ObjecId("111111123231111"),
 }
]`

Comment: can i do this with every 6 months top users?